# Работа указателей в Си

Tags: c, указатели

Пытаюсь я разобраться с указателями. Вроде как начал их понимать, но после этих двух простейших функций и их результатов сбился конкретно.
Почему функция swap() работает нормально, а функция sum() вообще не работает? Как сделать так, чтобы sum() заработала. Всем заранее спасибо!

P.S. в функции sum() пробовал убирать звездочку при операции суммирования - непомогло.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sum(int* c1, int* c2) {
    *c1++;
    *c2++;
}
void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
int main() {
    int c1 = 1;
    int c2 = 2;
    sum(&c1, &c2);
    swap(&c1, &c2);
    printf("c1 = %d, c2 = %d\n", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
с1 = 2, с2 = 1
```

Comment: `(*c1)++;    (*c2)++;` - из-за приоритета операторов нужны скобки.

Comment: @Harry спасибо большое, это сработало! Но я не очень понял, а что такое приоритет операторов?

Comment: @ancores, это характеристика порядка исполнения операций. Подробнее [здесь](https://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0064/).

Answer (score 1):

`(*c1)++;    (*c2)++;` - из-за приоритета операторов нужны скобки.